# python import module error in PyQt5

Tags: 20.04, python3, pyqt5

I am trying to install this application https://github.com/Superzchen/iLearnPlus
I followed the Method 2 for installing the application.
When I tried running it

```
python iLearnPlus.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iLearnPlus.py", line 5, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QMessageBox, QAction, QFileDialog)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

pyqt is already installed

```
pip install PyQt5
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (5.14.1)
```

Tried this also as suggested:

```
python3 iLearnPlus.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iLearnPlus.py", line 5, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QMessageBox, QAction, QFileDialog)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

Can someone help please.

Comment: try ```python3``` instead of ```python```, ```pip3``` instead of ``` pip```. probably you have installed 2 python versions, and 1 pip version. probably that's the reason why it's causing this isuee

Comment: @RishonJR added that suggestion in the problem statement.....Kindly see...error is the same